# Checking if image is mostly black and white or color

Tags: python, image-processing

[image]I am trying to classify if an image mostly contains black and white or color, to be precise it is a photo of a photocopy(think xerox),which is mostly black and white.The image is NOT single channel image, but a 3 channel image.

I just want to know if there are any obvious ways to solve this that im missing.

for now im trying to plot histograms and may be do a pixel count, but that does not look very promising,any suggestions on this would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean real BW or grayscale?

Comment: The image is a color image, but the dominant object in the image will be a black and white object.

Comment: Do you have an example image?`

Comment: sure ,give me a minute to post

Comment: as you see, the image is mostly black and white,but not entirely.

Comment: Is that image not all black and white? I guess I could imagine some yellow in the hair but looks fully black and white tbh. Edit: Okay used a color picker and indeed it does have some color, it's just very desaturated.

Comment: To find whether or not a certain pixel is grayscaleish the easiest way to do it is to compare the three values of the three channels. If the three are similar then the color is a value of gray (white and black also fulfill this property).

Comment: so what do you suggest @SilverSlash ?

Comment: @Ryan I think if you can compute the average color saturation value that might be an easy test to determine if the image is mostly black & white (desaturated).

Comment: What do you mean by compute average color saturation, average all the three channels?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of the exact use case, but having experienced similar issues I used this rather helpful article.

https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/05/24/how-to-find-the-main-colours-in-an-image/

The GitHub containing the full code is found here: https://gist.github.com/jayapal/077f63f3163abbfb3c50c7d209524cc6

If this is for your own visual the histogram should be enough, if you are attempting to automate however, it may be helpful to round the color values up or down, this would provide information on if the image is darker or lighter than a certain value.

What are you using this code for on a larger perspective? Maybe that will help provide more adequate information

Edit: The code above also provides the ability to define a region of the image, hopefully this will make your selection more accurate

Adding code directly

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
import cv2
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("red.png")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Resize it
h, w, _ = image.shape
w_new = int(100 * w / max(w, h) )
h_new = int(100 * h / max(w, h) )

image = cv2.resize(image, (w_new, h_new));


# Reshape the image to be a list of pixels
image_array = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3))
print image_array
# Clusters the pixels
clt = KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
clt.fit(image_array)

def centroid_histogram(clt):
    # grab the number of different clusters and create a histogram
    # based on the number of pixels assigned to each cluster
    numLabels = np.arange(0, len(np.unique(clt.labels_)) + 1)
    (hist, _) = np.histogram(clt.labels_, bins = numLabels)

    # normalize the histogram, such that it sums to one
    hist = hist.astype("float")
    hist /= hist.sum()

    # return the histogram
    return hist


# Finds how many pixels are in each cluster
hist = centroid_histogram(clt)

# Sort the clusters according to how many pixel they have
zipped = zip (hist, clt.cluster_centers_)
zipped.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x : x[0])
hist, clt.cluster_centers = zip(*zipped)

# By Adrian Rosebrock
import numpy as np
import cv2



bestSilhouette = -1
bestClusters = 0;

for clusters in range(2, 10):
    # Cluster colours
    clt = KMeans(n_clusters = clusters)
    clt.fit(image_array)

    # Validate clustering result
    silhouette = metrics.silhouette_score(image_array, clt.labels_, 
    metric='euclidean')

    # Find the best one
    if silhouette > bestSilhouette:
        bestSilhouette = silhouette;
        bestClusters = clusters;

print bestSilhouette
print bestClusters
```

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for your response .let me check this out and see if this works

Comment: Please copy relevant code part over here to prepare for link rot.

Comment: Thank you, all set

Comment: Since zip objects have no sort method, make it a list like:
  zipped = list(zip (hist, clt.cluster_centers_))